# 375 media query overriden 640 viewport

Tags: css, responsive-design

i want the body show body text color according to 375 viewport, 376-640 viewport, and default viewport.

here is the code

```css
.dllm {
  color: green;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 376px) {
  .dllm {
    color: red;
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) {
  .dllm {
    color: yellow;
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="dllm">

  aslkjfdlkdasjflk;asjflksajlfk aslkjfdlkdasjflk;asjflksajlfk

</body>
```

The css insdie 375 override everything, anyone know what is the problem?

https://jsfiddle.net/rq34ptx4/

Comment: I think it should be @media only screen and (max-width:375px) {  (changed to max-width)?

Comment: tried, everything turn to green.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rq34ptx4/1/ works fine is this jsfiddle

Comment: i found the chrome console responsive features not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `min-width:375px` and then again you have used `min-width:376px` that's why they collapsed. Instead use `max-width:375px` i.e you want `body text-color` to change till `375px viewport width` and below. Another declaration should be from `min-width:376px` to till `max-width:640px` i.e. change text-color in-between declared values.

Try below codes,

```css
body {
    color:green;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 640px){
  body{
    color:orange;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px){
  body{
    color:red;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

aslkjfdlkdasjflk;asjflksajlfk
aslkjfdlkdasjflk;asjflksajlfk

</body>
```